# Об уточнениях на латинице

Tags: уточнения, латиница-кириллица

> Западные общества... первыми стали «обществами индивидов», как следует
>   из концепции Норберта Элиаса (Norbert Elias).

При том, что имя автора концепции несложно, так ли необходимо давать имена, названия на латинице? Часто такие уточнения, загружая статьи, превращают чтение в преодоление бурелома. Когда же, и это плохо, такой приём не ставится в ранг принципа — начало цитируемого текста ниже приводится — возникает ещё вопрос: об уместности кириллицы.

> Недавнее исследование центра «Пью Ресерч»...

https://inosmi.ru/social/20180708/242676250.html

Comment: Давненько я не бывал на "Иносми", но насколько помню, уточнение латиницей на этом сайте является редакторской политикой, независимо от того чью статью переводят. Исключением являются только широкоизвестные имена, к которым Норберт Элиас не относится.

Comment: Согласен, соглашусь и с любой политикой, когда она объяснима, о чём и последняя фраза в вопросе. Впрочем, вопрос был общий, а текст выбранный — не самый характерный для перегруженного.

Answer (score 1):

Уточнять оригинальное написание имени или нет, решает автор. Мотивы могут разными: придание статье большей строгости (при цитатах в научном тексте такое уточнение может дополняться через запятую годом издания цитируемого материала, который может упоминаться или не упоминаться в списке литературы), желание исключить неточности обратного перевода имени (русская транскрипция не всегда однозначна) и пр. Elias встречается в качестве имени и фамилии, а разные варианты их английского написания могут приводить к недоразумениям: во многих печатных источниках встречается Norbert **Ellias** (с удвоением L), и не всегда можно разобраться, о том ли человеке речь. С именем же Elias чудеса случались и в самом английском: авторство композиций гитариста Бо Диддли (Bo Diddley, он же Elias МсDaniel) на пластинках записывалось с двумя ошибками: Ellas МсDaniels (на слух или по рукописным надписям на студийных коробках с лентой), в то время как по официальным авторским документам на них всё точно (как и на его надгробном камне). Что касается данного текста, по стилю он формален (насыщен статистикой с указанием процентов), и такое однократное уточнение ничего в нём не портит.